# When updating NFT metadata for a game, how can I ensure that the content in the passed tokenURI reflects the on-chain metadata?

Tags: nft, ipfs, games

I'm working on a game. There is a "equipment" item that has some stats such as experience, level, and rarity. The equipment is an NFT. I'm storing these stats (metadata) on-chain via a mapping on the NFT smart contract, as well as storing the tokenURI of the metadata formatted in JSON, hosted on IPFS.

Some of the equipment's metadata can change via in-game events. When this happens, the on-chain metadata (the mapping on the smart contract) is updated. I also want to update the tokenURI. My question is, where does this tokenURI come from? I believe it must come from outside the contract, but when and how is the JSON generated and uploaded to IPFS? I was thinking the game's front-end would do this prior to calling the smart contract function. But this raises a problem with users who do not use my front-end to play the game. Those users could call the smart contract function and pass a tokenURI containing metadata that is completely different from the metadata stored on-chain. This latter on-chain metadata would be the "real" one and the one used in all in-game calculations, but anyone who visits the tokenURI would see fake metadata.